# Fullcalendar Scheduler timeline view doesn't change the Slot's width

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to custom the Scheduler to make the slot larger but when I apply the width it doesn't work, curiosity the height do.

e.g

[image]

Someone know how to make it?

Comment: It is where is the "sala 1 "

Comment: You haven't shown us your code so we can't know what you did with width or whether it was correct or not

Answer (score 0):

```
resourceAreaWidth: "13%", // Determines the width of the area that
    contains the list of resources.
```

this one work for me in V5.